# PyQt5 styleSheet different results

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qtstylesheets

I am making a Python GUI using PyQt5 and its editor. Trying to put some colors to the thing I played around with styleSheet. But I encountered a different result when using it in a QMainQindow(left side of the image  and a QDialog(right side [desired look]). It is like it creates the same effect to every other widget.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Code from the QMainWindow

```
<property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <property name="styleSheet">
    <string notr="true">QWidget{
        background-color:qlineargradient(spread:repeat, x1:0, y1:1, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(39, 21, 103, 255), stop:1 rgba(94, 94, 140, 255))
        }

        QPushButton{
        background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0.915, y1:0.227273, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 255), stop:1 rgba(56, 56, 140, 255));
        font: 75 8.5pt &quot;Sitka Small&quot;;
        }

        QToolButton{background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0.915, y1:0.227273, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 255), stop:1 rgba(56, 56, 140, 255));
        font: 75 8.5pt &quot;Sitka Small&quot;;
        }

        QLabel{
        color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
        }

        font: 75 8.5pt &quot;Sitka Small&quot;
      </string>
   </property>
```

Code from QDialog

```
 <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Dialog</string>
  </property>
  <property name="styleSheet">
   <string notr="true">QDialog{
background-color:qlineargradient(spread:repeat, x1:0, y1:1, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(39, 21, 103, 255), stop:1 rgba(94, 94, 140, 255))
}

QPushButton{
background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0.915, y1:0.227273, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 255), stop:1 rgba(56, 56, 140, 255));
font: 75 8.5pt &quot;Sitka Small&quot;;
}

QToolButton{background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0.915, y1:0.227273, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 255), stop:1 rgba(56, 56, 140, 255));
font: 75 8.5pt &quot;Sitka Small&quot;;
}

QLabel{
color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

font: 75 8.5pt &quot;Sitka Small&quot;

</string>
  </property>
```

How can I have the look of the QDialog on the right at the QMainWindow?

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: The question is how can I have the look that is showing in the QDialog on the QMainWindow. I edited the post since the question was not obvious enough.

Answer (score 0):

I found [this QA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkCYO.png). Also the [Qt5 StyleSheet syndax page](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html) seems to comfirm that

```
<string notr="true">QWidget#centralwidget{
```

and left the rest of the Code from the QMainWindow unchanged.